# Expo Video Player loads to full screen

Tags: react-native, video, expo, video-player

I'm trying to build a react native video player using expo. The videoplayer is on a modal and basically, I want the video to load into fullscreen mode horizontally. I am able to hardcode a rotation of the video so that it is horizontal, but the controls are still in portait mode ([Video player image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iewn0.jpg)). How do I get the video to play in full screen mode? Here is the component's code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo-av'
import VideoPlayer from 'expo-video-player'
import BaseModal from './BaseModal';



type Props = {
  style?: object;
  setVisible: (visibility: boolean) => void;
  visible: boolean;
};

const RiteVideoPlayer: React.FC<Props> = props => {

  return (
    <BaseModal
      visible={props.visible}
      setVisible={props.setVisible}
    >
        <VideoPlayer
          slider={{
            visible: true
          }}
          style={{
            height: Dimensions.get("window").height
          }}
          videoProps={{
            rotation: 90,
            shouldPlay: true,
            resizeMode: Video.RESIZE_MODE_CONTAIN,
            source: {
              uri: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
            },
          }}
        />
    </BaseModal>
  );
};

export default RiteVideoPlayer;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  video: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: 500,
  },
  buttons: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Extra info: I tried using the Video component instead of the video player component for expo, and it allows the native controls full screen button to actually work, but still doesn't allow for rotation.